# CodeIgniter database session driver only MySQL and Postgres supported?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

For CodeIgniter, under the database session driver option, there is an important note below:

"Only MySQL and PostgreSQL databases are officially supported, due to lack of advisory locking mechanisms on other platforms. Using sessions without locks can cause all sorts of problems, especially with heavy usage of AJAX, and we will not support such cases. Use session_write_close() after you’ve done processing session data if you’re having performance issues."
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

We use MS SQL database. Does this mean we cannot use the database option for maintaining sessions?
What is the risk of using this option for MS SQL database?